# Mousedown event are triggering twitce?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I'm using jquery to check with button is pressed in my view (embedded) but first time going trew the process it wil work fine but later in the view you can choos to go back to change the amount of people you have chosen. On that point once comming back to the first part of the view the mousedown event that allow you to select the button and give them a collor triggering twice and that will enable the button but also instantly disabling the same button.

Atm i have tried to make it so that once going trew it once it would change a var that is outside of the function and was needed to be a specific word but for the if() but that dident work.

Including my code from line 308 to 334.
This code is for activing and deactiving a button. first time it goes trew it will search for the button that got pressed and add the class active to it if it doesent have it and vise versa.

```
    var selectPersonsFunction = function (event) {
        console.log('selectPerson')
        // alert( 'mothafucka');
        var button = $(event.target);
        var selectPersons = button.parent();
        if ($.isNumeric(button.text())) {
            // get_availablity();

            if (button.hasClass('active')) {
                selectPersons.find('button.btnplus').text('+');
                selectPersons.find('button.btnplus').val(0);
                selectPersons.find('button').removeClass('active');
                selectPersons.find('input').val(5);
                console.log('deactive');
            } else {
                selectPersons.find('button').removeClass('active');
                button.addClass('active');
                selectPersons.find('input').val(button.text());
                console.log('active');
            }
        }
    };

    $('.selectPersons button').mousedown(selectPersonsFunction);
```

what i expect is that the code will be triggerd twice like the first time it goes trew but then on the second time.
But the actual outcome is that it will just keep triggering the same amount as as you have gone back to the back to that embedded view

P.S. i do not get any errors

Edit 1:

i have included the part of my html code that is uses the jquery to add classes and other things.

```js
var selectPersonsFunction = function(event) {
  console.log('selectPerson')
  // alert( 'mothafucka');
  var button = $(event.target);
  var selectPersons = button.parent();
  if ($.isNumeric(button.text())) {
    // get_availablity();

    if (button.hasClass('active')) {
      selectPersons.find('button.btnplus').text('+');
      selectPersons.find('button.btnplus').val(0);
      selectPersons.find('button').removeClass('active');
      selectPersons.find('input').val(5);
      console.log('deactive');
    } else {
      selectPersons.find('button').removeClass('active');
      button.addClass('active');
      selectPersons.find('input').val(button.text());
      console.log('active');
    }
  }
};

$('.selectPersons button').mousedown(selectPersonsFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selectPersons" class="btn-group selectPersons" role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
  <button type="button" value="1" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-responsive buttons1234">1</button>
  <button type="button" value="2" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-responsive buttons1234">2</button>
  <button type="button" value="3" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-responsive buttons1234">3</button>
  <button type="button" value="4" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-responsive buttons1234">4</button>

  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button onclick="void(0)" id="amount_of_people_types--btnGroupDrop" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-lg btnplus buttons1234 btninputouter" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">+</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="amount_of_people-btnGroupDrop">
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <input id="amount" type="number" class="form-control btninput" name="amount_of_people_types" value="0" max="{{$amount_of_people_type->max_persons}}">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
     <button type="button" class="btn next-page ok">OK</button>
    </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edit 2

I forgot to say that me going back to the part of the html is done with a progress bar at the top of the page and does not reload the page what so ever. and ill make a filled to describe what i mean.

Edit 3

So tried to create a fiddle but becuse this code is local and made by me and my friend i cant seem to get it to work as the code is so bundled up in to many difrent files. I'm sorry about this.

Comment: I would advise you to show us your `HTML` it might give us a better idea why your event trigger twice

Comment: What @CarstenLøvboAndersen said. You probably bind the event handler again when you go back to that embedded view.

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle with the problem?

Comment: Your code is working fine, I'm unable to duplicate the problem you describe

Comment: Made a snippet for you with your code. Please edit the snippet so it reproduces your problem.